# Best way to duplicate a gameobject in unity 2019.4.23 (MRTK)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I was just wondering what the best way would be to duplicate game object in unity (MRTK) making sure that both gameobjects functions the same.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share your research.

Comment: I have tried just clicking on the game object and clicking duplicate. However, when I do this, the game objects do not function as they normally do in runtime.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instantiate(GameObjectToCopy);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html